# Homebrew portable-ruby generates warning messages

Tags: ruby, homebrew

How can we get rid of such ruby warning messages reported when I execute a Homebrew command on MacOS ?

```
brew upgrade
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/FileUtils.rb:1267: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::Entry_::S_IF_DOOR
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1267: warning: previous definition of S_IF_DOOR was here
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/FileUtils.rb:1540: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::Entry_::DIRECTORY_TERM
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1540: warning: previous definition of DIRECTORY_TERM was here
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/FileUtils.rb:1542: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::Entry_::SYSCASE
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1542: warning: previous definition of SYSCASE was here
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/FileUtils.rb:1595: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::OPT_TABLE
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1595: warning: previous definition of OPT_TABLE was here
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/FileUtils.rb:1649: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::LOW_METHODS
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1649: warning: previous definition of LOW_METHODS was here
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/FileUtils.rb:1656: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::METHODS
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1656: warning: previous definition of METHODS was here
```

Answer (score 1):

This is [the open issue](https://github.com/knative/homebrew-client/issues/19) for the camel case warnings.

Comment: So apparently some updates introduces `FileUtils.rb` while the require should always be lower case - `fileutils.rb`